# Detecting What Is Capturing Clicks on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I'm getting a weird situation that I *think* is only when I'm plugged into a USB-C Hub on Windows 10.

OCCASIONALLY when I'm using my computer, it feels like there's another window that goes to the front and is there only when I click. Keystrokes are not affected, but, when this condition starts, when I try to click on any window, the window goes to the background so nothing gets clicked on.

I can control+tab back to get the underlying window to be the front, but the second I click again, it goes to the background.

I've tried following all the instructions here - https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-prevent-programs-from-stealing-focus-in-windows-2624453 - to detect what is grabbing focus, but nothing appears.

Once this condition happens, the only think I can do is ctrl+alt+delete and click the "task manager" entry. Interestingly, I have to click it *twice* - the first click always gets lost, and the second one brings up task manager as expected.

Is there anything I can do to log what's going on here?

Comment: Try a different hub... it could be defective, temporarily losing connectivity, or it could even contain malware, though that's less likely:: https://cybersecuritynews.com/malicious-usb-devices/ . Also, it may not be getting sufficient power, or your laptop occasionally cuts power to USB when on battery.

Answer (score 0):

This is a program you can make on your computer *WinList.exe list the open windows and their child windows' Window Title, Window Class, and the EXE file* - https://winsourcecode.blogspot.com/2019/05/winlistexe-list-open-windows-and-their.html

This shows two taskbar menus

```
  Favorites                        ToolbarWindow32  True    22022042        11010418        2752    11316   explorer.exe

  Desktop                          ToolbarWindow32  True    26544204        11010418        2752    11316   explorer.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

The
[Window Focus Logger](https://www.adminscope.com/downloads/window-focus-logger/)
worked well for me to find when the focus is stolen by another program, and which
program stole it.

Using the GUI version `WindowFocusLoggerGUI.exe`, rather than the Console version,
worked better for me.